# How to implement custom method of CrudRepository in Spring boot 2.0?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, repository

I can find this question has been asked earlier. But neither the answer nor the documentation is working for me. I follow [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) doc.

I would like to add 2 custom interface to the repository. I must be doing something wrong in my code.

**The compiler gives error:**

> Error:(18, 8) java: com.ma.home.service.BuyerPartyDetailsServiceImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method deleteAll() in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.

**Custom repository:**

```
  @Repository
  public interface CustomBuyerPartyDeatilsDAO {
    @Query("SELECT b FROM BuyerPartyDetails buyer WHERE LOWER(buyer.xmlFileName) = fileName")
    public List<BuyerPartyDetails> listByfileName(String fileName);

    @Query("SELECT b FROM BuyerPartyDetails buyer WHERE LOWER(buyer.buyerOrganisationName) = name")
    public BuyerPartyDetails getByBuyerPartyByName(String name);

}
```

**Repository:**

```
  @Repository
  public interface BuyerPartyDetailsDAO2 extends 
CrudRepository<BuyerPartyDetails, Long>, CustomBuyerPartyDeatilsDAO {

    public List<BuyerPartyDetails> listByfileName(String fileName);
    public BuyerPartyDetails getByBuyerPartyByName(String name);
}
```

**Service:**

```
   @Service
   public class BuyerPartyDetailsServiceImpl implements 
 BuyerPartyDetailsDAO2, 
  CustomBuyerPartyDeatilsDAO {


    @Autowired
    private BuyerPartyDetailsDAO2 buyerPartyDetailsDAO2;

    public BuyerPartyDetailsServiceImpl() {

    }

  // more implementation removed.  
 .......
 .......
 }
```

If I provide the implementation for `deleteAll()`, it asks one by one all the `CrudRepository` methods such as `save()`, `saveAll()`, `findById()`, `findAll()`, etc.

So how can use `CrudRepository` already implemented methods?

Comment: Override it. Abstract can be inplemented

Comment: Do I have to implement all the abstract method from CrudRepository?

Comment: `SELECT b FROM BuyerPartyDetails buyer` wrong alias, should be  `SELECT buyer`

Comment: thanks. But still, it doesn't answer my question. Provide the implementation of the all CrudRepository abstract method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error

> com.ma.home.service.BuyerPartyDetailsServiceImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method deleteAll() in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

you have to override all abstract methods and provide implementation for them to make it functional.

If you don't need to implement them all then you have to inject DAO interfaces into services and let the services implement their own interfaces.

Spring will do the rest by providing suitable implementation of your interfaces that you should configure in the application context.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I would like to use Spring's suitable implementation. You mentioned I have to configure it in the application context. How to configure it in the application context? Pls let me know?